# How can I speed up my MySQL update query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I recently deployed a new feature to my server where the API will take a large JSON string an store it in the database. This works fine in isolation but under load it quickly cripples my server. I'm looking to speed it up any way that I can.

Here is my table schema:

```
| id           | int(11)      |
| code         | varchar(255) |
| uuid         | varchar(255) |
| data         | longtext     |
| last_updated | datetime     |
```

Here are the indexes on the table:

[image: Indexes]

Finally, here's the update query:

> update backups set data = :data, last_backup_date = NOW() where uuid = :uuid limit 1

I can't imagine that the query is that slow itself, but the way that I'm storing the data may be fundamentally wrong. I've read online that storing the data on files in the filesystem is quicker, and also that decoupling data from the table (having a `backups_data` and `backups` table for example) is also quicker. What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to present the schema.  I can't see what Engine is being used.  What do the index(es) look like?  That is very important for performance.  How can `code` be unique, yet have a low cardinality?

How big is the `data` for the row in question?  If it is megabytes, then it could take seconds or minutes to shovel that much data around.

Was anything else going on with that table at the same time as the slow Update?  (Here the Engine becomes quite important.)